# How do I run multiple behave+python tests simultaneously without errors?

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, python-behave

I have a python web application that uses behave for behavioral testing.  I have 5 *.feature files that each take a few minutes to run when I run them, both locally and on our Jenkins build server.  I would like to run the five files in parallel rather than sequentially to save time.  I can do this locally, but not on my build server.  Here are the details:

Locally runs on Windows:

- I can run all 5 files in separate command windows using these command:

  - `behave.exe --include "file_01.feature"`
  - `behave.exe --include "file_02.feature"`
  - `behave.exe --include "file_03.feature"`
  - `behave.exe --include "file_04.feature"`
  - `behave.exe --include "file_05.feature"`
- I can also run a python script that spins off 5 separate processes using the same command.
- Both of these work, I have no problems

Build server runs on Linux:

- When I try to run all five files using a similar command, some of the behave scenarios give me errors.  The errors are one of these three:

  - *Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer*
  - *Message: chrome not reachable*
  - *Message: no such session*
- The behave scenarios that throw these errors seem to change with every test run.
- Oddly, if I rearrange the 5 *.feature files into 3, it works.  This is not an ideal solution though.  Our application is growing.  We'll have more feature files as it grows.

I suspect that there is some shared resource between the chrome drivers in the running behave tests, but I'm not sure.  I can't explain why this works for me locally, but not on my build server.  Nor can I explain why 3 files work, but not 5.

Has anyone seen errors like this when trying to run multiple behave tests simultaneously?  Or do you know what I should be looking for?  My project is big enough that it'd be difficult to put together a minimal example of my problem.  That's why I haven't posted any code.  I'm just wondering what I should be looking for, because I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I running multiple features in parallel way.

```
from behave.__main__ import main as behave_main

@step(u'run in parallel "{feature}" "{scenario}"')
def step_impl(context, feature, scenario):
    t = threading.Thread(
        name='run test parallel',
        target=parallel_executor,
        args=[context, feature, scenario])
        #args=[context, 'parallel_actions.feature', 'Make Cab-Cab communication'])
    t.start()


def parallel_executor(context, feature_name, scenario):
    os.chdir(testenv.PARALLEACTIONS_PATH)
    behave_main('-i "{}" -n "{}" --no-capture --no-skipped'.format(feature_name, scenario))
```

And feature

```
Feature: testing parallel
  Scenario: parallel run
    When run in parallel "parallel_actions-1.feature" "Make Cab-Cab communication"
    And run in parallel "parallel_actions-1.feature" "Another Scenario"
    And run in parallel "another_parallel.feature" "Another Scenario 2"
```

I just create new thread and call behave executor directly, you don't need call behave.exe process 5 times separately but once. All features are executed at same time as parallel.

I cant answer your message errors, but you can try another approach (more behave way) to run behave features as parallel.

Comment: Could  you explain the "os.chdir(testenv.PARALLEACTIONS_PATH)" line please @PeterZosiak

Comment: Hi @ISHAR , this step is optional, just changing working directory to avoid problems with full path to feature.

Comment: Hi @PeterZosiak, thanks for your help. I'm getting a "RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually." I believe it's due to the fixture being updated simultaneously. Any advice on how to deal with this moving forward?